# Make DataGridView Show Properties of Derived Class Objects when Using List of Base Class Objects

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, datagridview, .net-3.5

Is there any way to have `DataGridView` show the properties of my derived class if the members are held in a list of the base class type, in which the properties don't exist?  Say I have the following:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
public int MyPropertyBase { get; set; }
//...
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
public int MyPropertyDerived { get; set; }
//...
}

// Create list of type MyBaseClass, holding MyDerivedClass objects
List<MyBaseClass> list = new List<MyBaseClass>();
list.Add(new MyDerivedClass(1));
list.Add(new MyDerivedClass(2));
list.Add(new MyDerivedClass(3));

// Declare DataGridView
DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

// Create display column for DataGridView
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
```

When I bind a list to a `DataGridView` and show the `MyPropertyBase` property it works fine:

```
// Select MyPropertyBase to display in column
col.DataPropertyName = "MyPropertyBase";
dataGridView.Columns.Add(col);
dataGridView.DataSource = list;
```

However, if instead I want to show the `MyPropertyDerived` using the same `List<MyBaseClass>` it won't work and just shows empty cells (although it shows the number of cells corresponding to items in my list):

```
// Select MyPropertyDerived to display in column
col.DataPropertyName = "MyPropertyDerived";
dataGridView.Columns.Add(col);    
dataGridView.DataSource = list;
```

I really need to keep this list typed to my abstract base class since it is used elsewhere in the code all over the place.  Is there any way to expose the derived class properties to the `DataGridView` if they exist and just display and empty cell if the property doesn't exist?  What would really be helpful is to have each of the derived classes expose (through attributes perhaps) everything they would like to display when bound to a `DataGridView` and just have the `DataGridView` fill itself in from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to cast back each element in the list,do the next change and you will get 1,2,3 in the datagridview:

```
col.DataPropertyName = "MyPropertyDerived";
dataGridView.Columns.Add(col);
dataGridView.DataSource = list.ConvertAll(c => c as MyDerivedClass);
```

Comment: This is kind of the solution I think I'm stuck with. Currently I'm going to try and cast everything to an anonymous type which has all the properties I want.

Comment: with this i did you will have access to any property in derived,like if your derived class also as a property named foo in datapropertyname you can place the string foo and it will display its value.

Answer (score 1):

if you implement ITypedList and modify the return of method GetItemProperties this can bypass the limitation of the Data Binding CurrencyManager